# 1M records database query optimization

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users with around 1 million records "contacts".
And we keep a log of the emails we sent in another table "log_sent" which is also around 1M records.

We need to find which users havn't received our newsletter yet.
So i am using the following query to get the next user we need to send to:

```
SELECT contact.* 
FROM contacts AS contact
LEFT JOIN log_sent AS sent ON sent.contact_id = contact.id
WHERE sent.id IS NULL 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This is what the EXPLAIN query returns:

```
id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra
  1 | SIMPLE      | contact | ALL  | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                       | 1031628 | 
1 | SIMPLE      | sent    | ref  | contact_id    | contact_id | 4       | admin_marketing.contact.id | 1       | Using where; Not exists
```

The log_sent table has `contact_id` indexed.
The contacts table has `id` as the **primary index**.

This query take about **`1.8`** seconds to execute.
And the log_sent table is growing so this will be problematic. How can I optimize this query.

For what i understand it seems that the query is search all 1 million records in the contacts table. But there is really no index i can use to limit the number of users used.
Or maybe i'm missing something ?

Comment: Are you using this query in a loop in order to send out an email to each user? If so, you end up performing a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> invisal, this wouldn't work since we send different newsletters at
>   different times. So i would need to add a new field for every campaign
>   we're going to do

Then do like what @Denis has suggested. You do not need to create new table for every different newsletters. Here is the mock-up schemas:

```
contacts (contact_id, ...)
newsletter_campaign (campaign_id, campaign_name)
newsletter_sending (campaign_id, contact_id)
newsletter_log (campaign_id, contact_id, send_date)
```

**Create New Campaign**

- Insert all the contacts into newsletter_sending with a single query:
- `INSERT INTO newsletter_sending SELECT {$new_campaign_id}, contact_id
  FROM contacts;`.

**Sending a newsletter to a contact**

- Remove contact from the newsletter_sending list and add to log
- `DELETE FROM newsletter_sending WHERE campaign_id = {$campaign_id} AND contact_id = {$contact_id}`
- `INSERT INTO newsletter_log VALUES({$campaign_id, {$contact_id}, NOW())`

**Query users that haven't received your newsletter**

- `SELECT * FROM newsletter_sending WHERE campaign_id = {$campaign_id}`

**Query users that have received your newsletter**

- `SELECT * FROM newsletter_log WHERE campaign_id = {$campaign_id}`

The reason that I insist you to change is because your current schema does not scale. It will getting slower and slower when contact and log are getting bigger and bigger

Comment: invisal, this wouldn't work since we send different newsletters at different times. So i would need to add a new field for every campaign we're going to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but still it requires you to change your table design.

Comment: That's what I implemented. Thanks for the insight and the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* only need a single row, rewriting the query so it uses a `not exists` clause might make a difference:

```
SELECT contact.* 
FROM contacts AS contact
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM log_sent AS sent WHERE sent.contact_id = contact.id )
LIMIT 1
```

If it doesn't I'd suggest reversing your logic. Create a "sending" table, and fill it up when an email needs to be sent. Delete from it (and add to your logs table) as you send new emails.

Comment: Denis, reversing the logic is a great idea but it wouldn't work when we have multiple campaigns running. I would have to create a "sending" new table for every campaign we start. Right ?

Comment: and i got same results when using the NOT EXISTS conditions. Both your query and the original one loaded in about 2 seconds

Comment: You could use the same table with a campaign_id field... Re the not exists, I'm not entirely surprised. (fwiw, I'm not even certain of whether Postgres would do a better job, because there's no reasonable index to use in practice.)

Comment: Denis, that makes sense...I ended up implementing this. thanks !